# Use boost strand and std::mutex

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

Follow up on this [site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html)

The Article **HTTP Server 3**

They're using **stand** to **guarantee that none of those handlers will execute concurrently.**

so, I have 3 threads that calls io_context.run() and which leads them to enter to channel and may have to use vector's push_back at the same time.

Do I have to use a std::mutex to lock push_back function to prevent them call concurrently or it well managed by **strand**?

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the code part in question and a litte more explaination, so readers will not have to find all that information themseleves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all of your code is correctly running within the strand then only one thread will be executing your code at a time.

The thread that is executing your code will change between the three threads that are available but only one function will be executing at a time.

You therefore shouldn't need mutexes, this is the part of the idea of using strands as mutexes are difficult to use correctly in asynchronous code.

Comment: I mean, when async_read the packet from client and server process its data that may lead to call push_back twice (assume two client send the same packet id with same time) from multithread that is running io_context.run()
And strand that managed this to prevent calling twice?

Comment: yes, if the `async_read` callbacks are in the same strand they will run sequentially not concurrently.

Comment: and then what is the point of running io_context.run() in multithread when async_read can be called only in one thread ?

Comment: if you only have one strand in your whole program then there is no point having multiple threads in your io_context. normally you would have a strand per connection

Comment: We have strand per connection.
I am afraid that many clients call the same handle which has push_back which is not a  thread safe to call in multiple thread

Comment: In this case, we must have mutex to lock a scope , am i right? because I have a global std::vector to use push_back that can call by multiple clients at the same time

Comment: yes, if you are using multiple strands you need a mutex, you should try to hold the mutex for a minimum amount of time to prevent it becoming a bottleneck

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and sorry for what I have just done.